# Show/Hide div element on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have the following div:

```
<div class="margin-bottom hidden-xs"></div>
```

This div is hidden, when window is small by using bootstrap class 'hidden-xs', but I need to show/hide this div when user click on the button.
I am new in web, so question is how to do it in a proper way, by using angular, bootstrap...

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: You don't have to go for angular or bootstrap. You can do it by using JavaScript only and its quite easy

Comment: You can use jquery. Look in to the `click()` event and the `toggle()` function. Give it a go and show your code and we can help you out if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-click. In your ng click you switch value from variable display. The directive ng-show / ng-hide work on css. If you need remove element from the DOM use ng-if instead of ng-show

**JS**

```
$scope.display = true;
$scope.switch = function(){
    $scope.display =! $scope.display;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="margin-bottom hidden-xs" ng-show="display"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="switch()">Click me !</button>
```

or if you don't need javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="display = true">
<div class="margin-bottom hidden-xs" ng-show="display"></div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="display =! display">Click me !</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button onclick="myfunction()">Hide/Show</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<script>
function myfunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle a display using only javascript you can try this

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrdKEM
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('margin-bottom')[0];
  toggle.style.display = toggle.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom hidden-xs">
  <h1>hello world</h1>
</div>
<input type="button" value="hide and show" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be easily done using javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('showHide');
    if (x.style.opacity === '0') {
        x.style.opacity = '1';
    } else {
        x.style.opacity = '0';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="showHide" class="margin-bottom hidden-xs" onclick="myFunction()">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: As the OP is using AngularJS, this is not the best solution.